# If my app was granted FileSystem access, browser/computer shutdown and restarted, do I need to call "webkitRequestFileSystem" again?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

Everytime I want to access the filesystem, does my app need to call `webkitRequestFileSystem`? Or is there some way to persist the filesystem stored in a variable across shutdowns and restarts?

For example:

1. Request Quote and the filesystem
2. On granted, store the returned `DOMFileSystem` object in a variable
3. User shuts down chrome and computer
4. User starts chrome up again
5. My app wants to access file system, what does it do?

It's a hosted app, but this question also applies to any web app I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always need to request a FileSystem, if that's what you need. To use the same one each time use a PERSISTENT type when requesting the file system.

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, size, successCallback, opt_errorCallback);
```

There are other local storage options that might suit you better if making this request is too onerous.

Comment: it's not too onerous, I just want to make sure I'm always getting the same filesystem/sandbox.